# Apple M1 Chip does not support chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle, spock, apple-m1

We have acceptance tests that use gradle build with the following configuration:

```
webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver chromeDriverVersion
    geckodriver geckoDriverVersion
}
```

where:

```
    chromeDriverVersion = '95.0.4638.17'
    gebVersion = '5.1'
    geckoDriverVersion = '0.30.0'
```

Starting it under Mac **Intel** Architecture works fine. But under **ARM** (Apple M1 Chip) I am getting following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':configureChromeDriverBinary'.
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Is there any way to fix it?